# How can we exclude results from users with no tty in auditd?

Tags: linux, audit, tty

We have existing auditd rules that log all commands except for UID 501 and it works well:

```
% cat /etc/audit/audit.rules
-D
-b 320
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F uid!=501
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S execve -F uid!=501
```

They result in data like:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1493677870.320:573818): arch=c000003e syscall=59 
success=yes exit=0 a0=18e0d80 a1=18e9ac0 a2=18df340 a3=20 items=2 
ppid=29928 pid=29943 auid=4294967295 uid=501 gid=103 euid=501 suid=501
fsuid=501 egid=103 sgid=103 fsgid=103 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 
comm="bb" exe="xxxx" key=(null)
```

We want to however omit commands logged that don't have no TTY like that above: "**tty=(none)**" choosing to only log SYSCALL's for valid TTY's e.g. "**tty=pts1**"

After hours of reading through auditd documentation I've exhausted all avenues for how to get this done. While there are hooks for uid, euid etc, there doesn't appear to be one for tty and if so how do you denote a null tty when "(none)" is just a text representation of NULL in the logging code.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a python scrypt to cutting logs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sh import tail
from datetime import datetime
import re
import socket
import time


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1" #changeme (send to remote server)
UDP_PORT = 5555 #changeme (send to remote server)
logfile = '/var/log/audit_commands.log'


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
hostname = socket.gethostname()



def callback(m):
    try:
        m = m.group(0)
        m = m[1:]
        return '='+m.decode('hex')
    except:
        return '='+m


for line in tail("-F", "/var/log/audit/audit.log", _iter=True):
    if "type=SYSCALL" and "tty=pts" not in line:
        continue
    _,msg=line.strip().split('msg=')
    aid,exe = msg.split(": ",1)
    time, id = aid.split(":",1)
    time = int(time[6:16])
    time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    logTable = line.split(' ')
    success=logTable[4]
    comm=logTable[24]
    auid=logTable[29]
    euid=logTable[32]
    log_entry="timestamp='"+time+"'"+" "+"address='"+hostname+"'"+" "+comm+" "+success+" "+auid+" "+euid+"\n"
    #sock.sendto(bytes(log_entry, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))  #uncomment if you set ip/port
    try:
        log_file = open(logfile, 'a')
        log_file.write(log_entry)
        log_file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).